# Appears horizontal scrollbar after minimizing listview that has auto-resize columns width

Tags: c#, .net, listview, scrollbar

I have ListView which sets the width of columns depending on size:

```
public class CommonListView : ListView
{
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        int columnWidth = (ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth - 6) / Columns.Count;
        foreach (ColumnHeader column in Columns)
            column.Width = columnWidth;
    }
}
```

I added listview on a form and set anchor property to 'All' (Top | Bottom | Left | Right).
When I change the size of a form all working correctly. But when I maximize a form (via maximize box) and minimize after that columns have correct size, but appears horizontal scrollbar which should not be. 
[image]

If I click on it (without changing the size of columns or listview), it will disappear.

What should I do to make this scrollbar did not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that I have found to solve my problem described below.

```
    private FormWindowState _previouseFormWindowState;

    private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_previouseFormWindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized && WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            var si = new SCROLLINFO();
            if (GetScrollInfo(listView, ref si, ScrollBarDirection.SB_HORZ))
            {
                if (si.nMax < si.nPage)
                {
                    ShowScrollBar(listView.Handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_HORZ, false);
                }
            }
        }
        _previouseFormWindowState = WindowState;
    }

    public enum ScrollInfoMask : uint
    {
        SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
        SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
        SIF_POS = 0x4,
        SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
        SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
        SIF_ALL = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS),
    }

    public enum ScrollBarDirection
    {
        SB_HORZ = 0,
        SB_VERT = 1,
        SB_CTL = 2,
        SB_BOTH = 3
    }

    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SCROLLINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint fMask;
        public int nMin;
        public int nMax;
        public uint nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int wBar, bool bShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, int fnBar, ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);

    public static bool GetScrollInfo(Control ctrl, ref SCROLLINFO si, ScrollBarDirection scrollBarDirection)
    {
        if (ctrl != null)
        {
            si.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.fMask = (int)ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;
            if (GetScrollInfo(ctrl.Handle, (int)scrollBarDirection, ref si))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```